# facebook and twitter appid and app secretid

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter

I am developing an application in Android and the iPhone. In this application I am integrating both, Facebook and twitter. My question is: is it possible to use the same Facebook App ID for both Android and the iPhone. As well as the same Twitter App ID and App Secret for both the iPhone and Android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the same ID in both android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

you can use same application id no problem. Remember this application id is not Os Specific